# Visual Studio Code Save All button issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code Save All button is always enabled even without any file changes. How can we solve this issue? Ideally it should be grayed Out if no file changes are there in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

It's an intentional feature, just in case someone is not sure if they saved their files, VS Code will always show it to prevent closing without saving (besides the exit prompt).

Now, if for some reason they decided to change this, it would we worse, as people are used to the *always blue* button.